# Trouble with making a piglatin converter

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, slice, charat

Okay so I'm having some trouble trying to get this to remove everything before the first vowel, adding it to the end, and then adding "ay" to the end of that

```
    function translate(word) { // put first constants at end && add "ay" 
      var result = word;
      var end = "WillBeOverrideN";
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (result.charAt(i) === ("a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u")) {
          end = result.slice(0, i-1); // everything b/f vowel
          result = result.slice(i-1); // everything after && vowel 
          result += end; 
          break; 
        }
      }
      result += "ay";
      return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change function slightly, 
here is the working function

```
function translate(word) { // put first constants at end && add "ay" 
      var result = word;
      var last = "WillBeOverrideN";
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if(["a","e","i","o","u"].indexOf(result[i]) !== -1){      

          last = result.slice(0, i); // everything b/f vowel
          result = result.slice(i); // everything after && vowel 
          result += last ; 
          break; 
        }
      }
      result += "ay";
      return result;
    }
```

Comment: what is the out put you are expecting for eight?

Comment: nevermind, there was a weird "ay" technicality in the assignment, it works